# Significant location changes monitoring stops while in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I have an app that checks if the user approaches one of my client's stores and when he does, the app sends him a notification telling him he is near a store.

Of course I'm using geofencing (`locationManager: didEnterRegion`) and I have more than 20 stores so on `locationManager: didUpdateLocations` I'm sorting the 20 nearest stores to the user.

I'm configuring my `CLLocationManager` this way on the `AppDelegate` and then setting my `ViewController` `locationManager` property to the object (because I want to use the same `locationManager` on the `AppDelegate` as well:

```
-(void)configureLocationManager
{
    //Initializing "locationManager"'s(CLLocationManager)
    self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    //Setting "locationManager"'s(CLLocationManager)'s delegate to "monitorLocationVC"(monitorLocationViewController)
    self.locationManager.delegate=self.monitorLocationVC;
    //Setting "locationManager"'s(CLLocationManager)'s distance filter to 10
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter=10;
    //Setting "locationManager"'s(CLLocationManager)'s activityType to navigation
    self.locationManager.activityType=CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
    //setting "locationManager"'s(CLLocationManager) desiredAccuracy to "best"
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    //Setting "locationManager"'s(CLLocationManager)'s pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to NO
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO;
    //If OS version is 9 or above - setting "allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates" to YES
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {
        self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
    }
}
```

Until now everything worked fine, but now I see that the app started not to notify for stores in the background after a few minutes it is running (notifies about 15 minutes and then suddenly stops).

Note: Sometimes when I launch my app from the home screen (just a normal launch) the app crashes, could it be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: check this https://github.com/voyage11/Location

Comment: @kb920 The app worked perfectly until now, so the code is correct, I am just searching for the bug that makes the app stops monitoring significant location changes

Comment: what is the crash log?

Comment: @kb920 I really don't know because is crashes on my iPhone when it's not connected to Xcode

Comment: @FS.O you can add https://crashlytics.com or https://mint.splunk.com/ to your project to get crash log from device in realtime. Or else check device crash logs in iPhone Settings diagnostics

Comment: yes it could be a problem. iOS might be unable to relaunch the app - plz check the reports as @aman.sood reported. -- also check the permissions thing

Answer (score 0):

check this documentation and add background fetch mode: [documentation apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html)

and add this code:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]) {
    [self.locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
}
```